# changing from django generic view to class based view

Tags: python, django

This is my blog/urls.py file and i am in Django 1.6, when i run my server it complains : Could not import django.views.generic.date_based.archive_index. Parent module django.views.generic.date_based does not exist. Please help me solve this. This is the tutorial i am using http://www.webmonkey.com/2010/02/Use_URL_Patterns_and_Views_in_Django

```
 from django.conf.urls.defaults import *

 from djangoblog.blog.models import Entry

 from tagging.views import tagged_object_list



  info_dict = {

'queryset': Entry.objects.filter(status=1),

'date_field': 'pub_date',

   }



   urlpatterns = patterns('django.views.generic.date_based',

(r'(?P<year>d{4})/(?P<month>[a-z]{3})/(?P<day>w{1,2})/(?P<slug>[-w]+)/$', 'object_detail', dict(info_dict, slug_field='slug',template_name='blog/detail.html')),

(r'^(?P<year>d{4})/(?P<month>[a-z]{3})/(?P<day>w{1,2})/(?P<slug>[-w]+)/$', 'object_detail', dict(info_dict, template_name='blog/list.html')),

(r'^(?P<year>d{4})/(?P<month>[a-z]{3})/(?P<day>w{1,2})/$','archive_day',dict(info_dict,template_name='blog/list.html')),

(r'^(?P<year>d{4})/(?P<month>[a-z]{3})/$','archive_month', dict(info_dict, template_name='blog/list.html')),

(r'^(?P<year>d{4})/$','archive_year', dict(info_dict, template_name='blog/list.html')),

(r'^$','archive_index', dict(info_dict, template_name='blog/list.html')),
```

)

Answer (score 1):

The new view for django.views.generic.date_based.archive_index is django.views.generic.dates.ArchiveIndexView. Refer to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/generic-views-migration/ for other migrations associated with Class Based Views

Comment: That tutorial is out of date - django removed the function generic views in 1.4. Class based views are kind of complex and poorly documented, unfortunately. I personally always end up reading the source code rather than bothering with the sparse documentation.

Comment: "Django's CBVs were a mistake" http://lukeplant.me.uk/blog/posts/djangos-cbvs-were-a-mistake/